# after installing ubuntu windows is not showing in grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 64-bit, 32-bit

Recently for one project I installed 64-bit Ubuntu (initially it was Ubuntu 32-bit) in my college lab machine.

But the problem is after installing 64-bit it is not showing me the windows in grub while booting and that windows is genuine which was purchased by my college(For my own machine I don't need windows ).

I tried many things to update it's grub but no result found. If I replace the 64-bit with 32-bit Ubuntu it will show windows option in grub menu.

- Why generally this kind of problems will happen ?.
- Can't we solve it with out replacing the 64-bit with 32-bit ?

Answer (score 2):

You could try boot repair:

make a [Boot-Repair-Disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and run Boot-Repair

Alternatively, boot off your Ubuntu Install CD and run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

then launch boot-repair